# Unable to insert row from Android to MySQL using PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to insert data from android to MySQL but it does not show any error in logcat but displays the json message in the app.

Here is my PHP script.

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */
 require("config.inc.php");
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['userContact']) && isset($_POST['userAddress']) && isset($_POST['userStore']) && isset($_POST['userRequest'])) {

    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $userContact = $_POST['userContact'];
    $userAddress = $_POST['userAddress'];
    $userStore = $_POST['userStore'];
    $userRequest = $_POST['userRequest'];


    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO userrequests(userName, contactNumber, userAddress, storeList, requestBody) VALUES('$userName', '$userContact', '$userAddress', '$userStore', '$userRequest')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "IsitdispllayingthusOops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here is my JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);

            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                Log.i("log_tag","Line reads: " + line);
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

}

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText userName, userContact, userAddress, userRequest;
    private Spinner userStore;
    private Button mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/register.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/callarocket/register.php";

    //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/register.php";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.StoreSpinner);
        String[] items = new String[]{"NZ Mamak", "Indo Shop", "NZ Supermarket"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

        userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditName);
        userContact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditContact);
        userAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditAddress);
        userStore = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.StoreSpinner);
        userRequest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditRequest);

        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new CreateUser().execute();

    }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Request...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = userName.getText().toString();
            String usercontact = userContact.getText().toString();
            String useraddress = userAddress.getText().toString();
            String userstore = userStore.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String userrequest = userRequest.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userContact", usercontact));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAddress", useraddress));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userStore", userstore));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userRequest", userrequest));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());


                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And the error I am getting inside the emulator is this json message in my php script

```
$response["message"] = "IsitdispllayingthusOops! An error occurred.";
```

I couldn't find the reason why new row cannot be inserted into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

POST can not be used by external applications. You have to use GET instead.

Comment: I have changed from POST to GET in this line JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "GET", params); but it's giving me this json message $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

Comment: Sorry, i'm not that far into Android development, so i don't know anything of the API's in use. But the change won't work anyway, you have to change everything to use GET instead of POST. In the case of the PHP part, just replace $_POST with $_GET, on the Android/Java part you have to consult the manual ;)